# Extending a correlated Subquery to include another query in LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am trying to extend a correlated subquery to include another query in LINQ.
In SQL, this would be the query.

```
SELECT V.Car_ID
FROM VEHICLES V, AGREEMENTS A, AGREEMENTS A1
WHERE A.Car_ID = V.Car_ID
AND enDate >= A.Hire_Start_Date
AND stDate <= A.Hire_End_Date
AND A1.CAR_ID = V.CAR_ID
AND location = A1.Return_Location
AND A1.Return_date =
 (SELECT MAX(A2.Return_Date)
 FROM AGREEMENT A2
 WHERE A2.VEHICLE_ID = V.VEHICLE_ID
 AND A2.Return_Date < stDate)**
```

With some help, I have got as far as querying if the vehicle has an agreement but I can't seem to extend it to check that the AGREEMENT return location matches the search location.  This is my code so far.

```
var cars = from v in db.VEHICLEs
                   where !db.AGREEMENTs.Any(a => (a.CAR_ID == v.CAR_ID
                   && a.STATUS_OPEN == true
                   && enDate >= a.HIRE_START_DATE
                   && strtDate <= a.HIRE_END_DATE))
                   select v;
```

The following part of the sql query is missing from my working LINQ query.

```
AND A1.CAR_ID = V.CAR_ID
AND location = A1.Return_Location
AND A1.Return_date =
 (SELECT MAX(A2.Return_Date)
 FROM AGREEMENT A2
 WHERE A2.VEHICLE_ID = V.VEHICLE_ID
 AND A2.Return_Date < stDate)**
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Apart from the sql section that is missing in Linq query, note the `!` symbol. Linq query doesn't seem to be equivalent to your sql query. It's selecting vehicles that do not have open agreement in a period, whereas sql query does the opposite but ignores STATUS_OPEN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Sql query is an inner join, so in Linq you can do:

```
var cars =  from v in db.VEHICLEs
            from a in db.AGREEMENTs
            from a1 in db.AGREEMENTs
            where a.CAR_ID == v.CAR_ID
                && enDate >= a.HIRE_START_DATE
                && strtDate <= a.HIRE_END_DATE
                && a1.CAR_ID == v.CAR_ID
                && location == a1.RETURN_LOCATION
                && a1.RETURN_DATE == db.AGREEMENTs
                    .Where(a2 => a2.VEHICLE_ID == v.VEHICLE_ID)
                    .Max(a2 => a2.RETURN_DATE)
            select v.CAR_ID;
```

For selecting additional fields you can do `select new { CarId = v.CAR_ID, ... }`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much derloopkat, you got me there!!! :-)

```
             var cars = from v in db.VEHICLEs                       
                   from a1 in db.AGREEMENTs
                   where !db.AGREEMENTs.Any(a => (a.CAR_ID == v.CAR_ID
                       && a.STATUS_OPEN == true
                       && enDate >= a.HIRE_START_DATE
                       && strtDate <= a.HIRE_END_DATE))
                       && a1.CAR_ID == v.CAR_ID
                       && schPickUpDepotID == a1.RETURN_LOCATION
                       && a1.HIRE_END_DATE == db.AGREEMENTs
                        .Where(a2 => a2.CAR_ID == v.CAR_ID)
                        .Max(a2 => a2.HIRE_END_DATE)
                   select v;
```